# Different style in corner radius between win 7 and win 10

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a styled `MenuItem` in XAML and it looks different between Windows 7 and Windows 10.

**MenuItem** code:

```
<MenuItem Click="LangMouseLeftButtonUp" ContextMenuOpening="LangMouseRightButtonUp" 
          x:Name="LangImageIcon">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="EN">
                    <Setter Property="Icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Border CornerRadius="20" Width="26" Height="26"
                                    Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="White" Background="Transparent"
                                           Text="EN" />
                            </Border>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Language.ActualLanguage}" Value="DE">
                    <Setter Property="Icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Border CornerRadius="20" Width="26" Height="26"
                                    Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="White" Background="Transparent"
                                           Text="DE" />
                            </Border>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

[image: This is how it looks in windows 7] How it looks in Windows 7

[image: And this is how it looks in Windows 10] How it looks in Windows 10

How can I change the behavior from Windows 10 so that it looks like Windows 7.  Or, how do I have to change the style so that Windows 7 shows the same button when I change the code so that it looks good in Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 defines the size for your icon windows 7 does not to fix this issue you just set the icon size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Windows 7 and Windows 10 uses different theme. Which in-turn defines the `Icon` sizes for the `MenuItem`. Ways in which you can solve this.

1. Try setting lesser `Height` and `Width` for your `Border`; If that works for you. *Somewhere around `18` will work i guess*.
2. Add below `ResourceDictionary` to your application / `MenuItem`'s `Resources`. This tells your WPF application to use **Aero** theme.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

> If you're not specifying the version and public key token, you’ll have to copy the theme assembly to the executable folder.

3. You can define `Template` to your `MenuItem` which avoids using `Icon` and you can get the same working for both the operating system versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dhilmathy. I tried to use a ResourceDictionary, but i did not work, because i defined a ResourceDictionary before. The usage of MergedDictionaries helped me out for this and now everything looks like it should!